# ffmpeg fails on conversion from .mov to .mp4 fails aT 98%

Tags: ffmpeg

Our code is below. When converting a uploaded `.mov` to `.mp4` the conversion halts at 98%.

Almost all of our other preferred formats encode flawlessly. Anyone has any clue on where we went wrong? We are struggling on this for a while now so we want to ask the experts, thanks in advance for any help.

```
<?php
$Path = dirname(__FILE__) . "/";
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace('\\', '/', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . "/";

session_start();
include_once 'inc/config.inc.php';
include_once 'common.php';
include_once 'inc/ffmpegprogressbar.class.php';

ob_flush();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Converting..........</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mainDiv{
            margin:auto 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #progressbar_pbText{
            display: block; margin-top: -22px;
        }
        #fileInformation{
            color: red; padding: 16px;
        }
    </style>
    <?php

// Specifie Inputfile for FFMPEG
    $count = count($_SESSION['Files']);
// $file  = array_pop($_SESSION['Files']);

    $FileInstance = array_pop($_SESSION['Files']);
    //$FileInstance = $_SESSION['Files'][0];
    $file = $FileInstance['FileName'];
    $passNeeded = $FileInstance['PassNeeded'];
    $fmt = $FileInstance['fmt'];

    $FFMPEGInput = $Path . 'data/' . $_SESSION['OldSession'] . "/" . $file;

    $timeUnique = time();
    //echo "Start:Session holds: ".$_SESSION["cstatus"].", cstatus var =   $cstatus";


  /*  if ($FileInstance['PassNeeded'] == 5) {
        $FFMPEGParams = "-r 1000 -ar 11025 -ab 32 -f $fmt -sameq -g 15 -s 1920x1080";
    } else if ($FileInstance['PassNeeded'] == 4) {
        $FFMPEGParams ="-r 1000 -ar 11025 -ab 32 -f $fmt -sameq -g 15 -s 1280x720";
    } else if ($FileInstance['PassNeeded'] == 3) {
        $FFMPEGParams = "-r 1000 -ar 11025 -ab 32 -f $fmt -sameq -g 15 -s 854x480";
    } else if ($FileInstance['PassNeeded'] == 2) {
        $FFMPEGParams = "-r 1000 -ar 11025 -ab 32 -f $fmt -sameq -g 15 -s 640x360";
    }
    */
if($fmt=="flv"){
if ($FileInstance['PassNeeded'] == 5) {
        $FFMPEGParams = "-r 1000 -ar 11025 -ab 32 -f $fmt -sameq -g 15 -s 1920x1080";
    } else if ($FileInstance['PassNeeded'] == 4) {
        $FFMPEGParams ="-r 1000 -ar 11025 -ab 32 -f $fmt -sameq -g 15 -s 1280x720";
    } else if ($FileInstance['PassNeeded'] == 3) {
        $FFMPEGParams = "-r 1000 -ar 11025 -ab 32 -f $fmt -sameq -g 15 -s 854x480";
    } else if ($FileInstance['PassNeeded'] == 2) {
        $FFMPEGParams = "-r 1000 -ar 11025 -ab 32 -f $fmt -sameq -g 15 -s 640x360";
    }
}elseif($fmt=="mp4"){
$FFMPEGParams = " -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 640x360";

}elseif($fmt=="ogv"){
$FFMPEGParams = " -acodec libvorbis -ac 2 -ab 96k -ar 44100 -b 125k -s 640x360";

}elseif($fmt=="webm"){
$FFMPEGParams = " -acodec libvorbis -ac 2 -ab 96k -ar 44100 -b 125k -s 640x360";
//}elseif($fmt!==""){
//-i %1 -s qvga -acodec libfaac -ar 22050 -ab 128k -vcodec libx264 -threads 0 -f   ipod %2
//-vcodec mpeg4 -acodec aac output.mp4
//$FFMPEGParams = "-r 20 -ar 44100 -ab 196 -f $fmt -s 480x351";
}
    if ($FileInstance['PassNeeded'] > 2) {
        $FileInstance['PassNeeded'] = $FileInstance['PassNeeded'] - 1;
        array_unshift($_SESSION['Files'], $FileInstance);
    }

    $flv_rpath = 'data/' . $_SESSION['OldSession'] . "/" . $file. $timeUnique . ".".$fmt;

     $FFMPEGOutput = $FFMPEGInput . $timeUnique . ".$fmt";

    $_SESSION['ConvertedFiles'][$file][] = array('Pass' => $passNeeded, 'OutFile' => $file . $timeUnique . ".$fmt","fmt"=>$fmt);



    if (!$_GET["pkey"]) {
        $pkey = rand();
    } elseif (file_exists('log/' . $_GET["pkey"] . '.ffmpeg')) {
        $pkey = $_GET["pkey"];
    } else {
        $pkey = rand();
    }

// initializing and create ProgressBar
    flush();
    $FFMPEGProgressBar = &new FFMPEGProgressBar();
    flush();
// Show Progressbar
    if ($count > 0) {
        if ($FileInstance['PassNeeded'] < 3) {
        define('FFMPEG_LIBRARY', '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg ');
        $extension = "ffmpeg";
        $extension_soname = $extension . "." . PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX;
        $extension_fullname = PHP_EXTENSION_DIR . "/" . $extension_soname;
            if (!extension_loaded($extension)) {
                dl($extension_soname) or die("Can't load extension $extension_fullname\n");
            }
            exec(FFMPEG_LIBRARY . " -y -i '" . $FFMPEGInput . "' -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:03 -an -vcodec png -f rawvideo -s 160x90 '$FFMPEGInput.png'");
        }
        $FFMPEGProgressBar->Show($pkey, $count, $url, $passNeeded, $file, $timeUnique,$fmt);
        if (!$_GET["pkey"] || !file_exists('log/' . $_GET["pkey"] . '.ffmpeg')) {
            flush();
            $FFMPEGProgressBar = &new FFMPEGProgressBar();
            flush();
            @$FFMPEGProgressBar->execFFMPEG($FFMPEGInput, $FFMPEGOutput, $FFMPEGParams, $pkey);

            flush();
            $_SESSION['new_space']["video"] = 'data/' . $_SESSION['OldSession'] . "/" . $file;
            $_SESSION['new_space']["{$FileInstance['name']}"] = $flv_rpath;
            $_SESSION['new_space']["session"] =   $_SESSION['OldSession'];
        }
    //echo "End:Session holds: ".$_SESSION["cstatus"].", cstatus var = $cstatus";
    } else {
//  header("Location: $url" . "index.php" );
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location.href='" . $url . "';</script><error>No Input</error>";
    }
// ShowProgressbar
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you show some output from FFmpeg when converting a `.mov` file? Also your code is very messy for us to understand. Try cleaning it up a bit, like removing commented lines and remove parts that doesn't matter, like the HTML and CSS.

Comment: Try ffmpeg manually, outside of any scripting, and include your ffmpeg command and the complete console output. Once it is working then you can try to integrate it into your scripting. [Do not use `-sameq`: it does not mean "same quality"](http://superuser.com/a/478550/110524) and has been removed from ffmpeg.